# How do I validate a textbox when it no longer has focus?

Tags: c#, validation

I would like to validate my textbox when the textbox is deselected.

It should validate the textbox value in the same way as [Google's Create Account page](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp).

If the textbox value passes validation it should proceed further otherwise it should show message like: `This value is not valid`.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: What will the textbox contain.  What will you need to validate?

Comment: It isn't clear whether you are talking about a web app or a desktop/WinForms app. Please add a tag for WinForms or WPF or ASP.Net to help you get the attention of the best helpers.

Answer (score 0):

Events of Validation And LostFocus can be you here.
Here is some code for validate textbox value
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.aspx

Answer (score 0):

if its a desktop app/WinForms u can use what Suspitsyn Kirill said, and for a web app it would be quite close.
The textbox has event handlers for on focus etc. using the code behind you can assign what the events will do.

Dont remember the C# ones exactly but it should be

```
private void textBox1_LostFocus(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1_Validating() 
}
```

add the lostfocus on the element to direct to this method.

You could also do it with javascript same concept.